# How can I delete git submodule wreckage?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

While pushing my code history to git repository, I found that Objective-C project work as a submodule, which means if I push Objective-C project, it work as a submodule, like [this](https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/-Obj-C--First-iPhone-Application-).

After I notice that factor, I tried to reinitialize my **.git** folder. (delete and tried to call 'git init')

But it would not work at all and submodules are still alive.

I also tried **git submodule deinit** and **init** command. However, after that, even though I tried to push my files to git repository, it throw out this message.

```
Sogos-Macbook:Test code dkswogus7530$ git push -u origin master

To https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I also tried to update & delete my git repository to type command **git pull origin master** and that command abort this message

```
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 537 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object d5c202897cf6f769235a2707d15719636fe37984:contains duplicate file entries
remote: fatal: Error in object
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review.git'
```

How can I resolve this problem?

This [submodule repository](https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review) pointed from [this](https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/-Obj-C--First-iPhone-Application-), [this](https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/-Obj-C--Fraction) and [this](https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/ACM-Craft).

Comment: git rm --cached 'submodule directory'

Comment: I tried that also, but it trow out THIS MESSAGE: Sogos-Macbook:Test code dkswogus7530$ git rm --cached ACM_craft
fatal: not removing 'ACM_craft' recursively without -r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails and you really just want to start again why not cd into the repo and each submodule and then:

```
rm -rd .git
```

Comment: It seems like work for the first time, but it also throw out this message. @Monte+Goulding

Comment: https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/JaehyunAhn/cpuls2_book_review.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Sogos-Macbook:Test code dkswogus7530$

Comment: I did say to do this only if you "really just want to start again". You aren't going to be able to push to an existing remote with a freshly initialised repo. Is there any problem with cloning the remote repo again and then copying your changes over?

Comment: Thanks Monte Goulding! It works within a new repository.

Comment: BTW, what is '-rd' stands for? I couldn't get it means.

Comment: Actually the d option is implied by r so it's redundant. r means recursively remove all the directories. see `man rm`